# How to show different websites in php for certain amounts of time?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm looking to make a webpage that will show a random web site (within the current web page) and only show it for 15 seconds then show another page, etc. I would like the web page to get the list of web sites to show from a MySQL database.

I'm not sure if this is possible to do in PHP because I know you can use iframes in Javascript, but if it's possible I'd like to do it in PHP. If anyone could point me in the right direction or write a little bit of code it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your HTML `head`:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="15;url=http://www.yourdomain.com">
```

Then, you can serve that page with a different iframe every time.

---

Here's an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Random website</title>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="15;url=http://www.yourdomain.com">
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe src="<?php echo $website_pulled_from_database; ?>"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: how would I go about having a different iframe every time I'm slightly confused

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sleep function in PHP instead of using jS if u are so adament on using pure PHP. But I see no point in doing that.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php
You should also look into ajax in PHP.

Comment: the reason I'm using php purely is so users can't change what they view or for how long, the reason being that can easily be changed when coding in javascript by the user

Comment: You should know that a user who is capable of editing a page's JS on the fly is likely to also be able to disable a meta refresh.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `header()` in PHP

```
header('refresh:15;url=http://www.google.com/');
```

The code above will redirect the user to Google after 15 seconds

Comment: This would be good, except I would like the user to stay on my webpage, sort of like iframes. I'm just not sure how to do this in php

Answer (score -1):

Well, I dont think u need to do this in pure PHP. You can retrieve the contents from the DB and display them at whatever time you want using javascript. You can use the setInterval function for javascript(jQuery).

for. eg:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
  $(function(){  
        var i=0;  
         $('li').not(':first').hide();//Hide everything other than the first li item  
          setInterval(function(){  
              $('li').eq(i).hide();//Hide the current li item  
              i++;    
              if($('li').eq(i).text().length==0) //check if it is the last li item  
                {  
                 i=0;  
                }  
              $('li').eq(i).fadeIn(1000); //FadeIn the next li item              
             },3000);                  
       });        
</script>
```

Hope this was of some help for you.

Comment: -1 The OP clearly said that he *doesn't* want to use Javascript.

Comment: Well, I was just pointing him in the right direction. This doesnt have to be pure PHP. He said he doesnt want to do this using iframes n jS.

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but yes I'm trying to stay away from javascript as it can be hacked very easily

Comment: I dont see your point. We are retriving the data from the DB using PHP, we are using jS just to display it on screen and add some flair. I dont think there's any risk involved in doing this. Can u please explain how this is risky? Anyways, did u checkout the sleep function in PHP?